# How to recognize the slightly 3D object

Tags: augmented-reality, wikitude

I am making the AR application. 
I would like to recognize slightly 3d object like this ,
(The buttons beside on the handle)

It looks like the both flat 2D image or 3D image ....
Howevere sometimes light or shadow disturbs the recognize ....

Then I think about some solution.

Do you thinkg 3D scanner and object recognition is helpfull for it? or 
2D normal recognize ,if so is there good way to recoginize (such as using many pattern of pictures depending on light)??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Standard image recognition algorithms work best when used with textured images with good image contrast. The scenario you are describing would require specific algorithms tailored to this special situation. OpenCV has a couple of algorithms that might help you in your use case (Feature Detection, Feature Descriptors).